# Rotate device overflow-x - :before/:after

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an issue with this code: http://jsfiddle.net/ftm9o335/1/
when I rotate the device seems that overflow-x on body doesn't do his work.

I think that the problem is this rule `.banner-strip:before, .banner-strip:after {width: 9999px;}`

So I'm thinking that this code doesn't works well.

How can I display an element with width 100% that goes before and after a element that is inside another element. 
I have to use jQuery?

I think that with the jsfiddle example everything is clear, it is difficult to explain.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the `.banner-strip` at `left:0;` and instead have a `padding: 5px 50px;` on it, you can remove the pseudo-elements and achieve the same result. You also need box-sizing to `border-box`, to include the paddings in the width.

```
.banner-strip {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 50px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 50px;
}
```

This assumes the pseudo-elements has no other use than "extending" the title on the left/right side.

Comment: but with this solution the h1 is not align with the other elements, because goes outside of the grid...
i would like to keep the position inside the grid, and add a colored bar outside the grid, so i think to the pseudo-class after-before.